# religious problem

Tags: indian-citizens, australia, religion

I m going to Australia for my studies after few months. I belongs to a Sikh religion. I am deeply religious and I carry a kirpan with me everytime and everywhere. And the airport security do not allow me to carry it with me. So what should I do? How can I overcome this?